# Django model and mptt integration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt

I have a django model like the following:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class deg_course_cat(models.Model):
    degree_code = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    category_level1 = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    category_level2 = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    category_level3 = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    min_credit = models.IntegerField()
    max_credit = models.IntegerField()
    primarystuff = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class deg_course_cat_mptt(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    min_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    max_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

# Create your models here.
```

The data in the django model deg_course_cat table look like the following:

[image]

I would like to create the mptt structure based on the model and its data i.e. something like the following structure:

[image]

How do i approach this problem? As i am kind of new to python, it would be great if i got a heads up on achieving this.

I have tried some code like the following but am not sure how correct it is:

```
from studentapp.models import deg_course_cat, deg_course_cat_mptt

#degreeroot = deg_course_cat_mptt.objects.create(name="DegreeRoot")

for degrees in deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('degree_code', flat=True):
    degreearray = set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('degree_code', flat=True))
    for i in range(0,len(degreearray)):
        degree(i) = deg_course_cat_mptt.objects.create(name= degreearray(i), parent=degreeroot)

        for categories_l1 in deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level1', flat=True):
        category_level1 = set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level1', flat=True))

            for categories_l2 in deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level2', flat=True):
            category_level2 = set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level2', flat=True))

            for categories_l3 in deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level3', flat=True):
            category_level3 = set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('category_level3', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967549/creating-mptt-from-a-django-model)

```
category_l1_array = list(set(deg_course_cat.objects.filter(degree_code=degree[i]).values_list('category_level1', flat=True)))
```